# firebase messaging notify all devices for a user

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to send a push notification to all devices for a particular user.
For example, when a new comment is added to the user's post.

My initial approach was to use a topic, but when subscribing to a topic it will only subscribe the device to the topic, not other devices.

My frontend is flutter and
I'm currently using firebase functions to send messages out.

Answer (score 0):

Every device has a token, you can request it by calling `FirebaseMessaging().getToken()`.
Every token is unique, so you can use them as document IDs `<- this is important`.

You need to create a collection where you store the tokens.
Every time the user logs in, request the token, and write user's ID to collection with the corresponding token, like this:

```
uploadToken(FirebaseUser user) async =>
    tokens.document(await FirebaseMessaging().getToken()).setData({
      'user': user.uid,
      'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
```

When you want to send a notification to a user, you just need to query all the documents where the `user` field's value is the same as the current `uid`.

And also, don't forget to delete the token document from the database when a user logs out.

```
removeToken() async => tokens.document(await FirebaseMessaging().getToken()).delete();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought of this approach. But then I realized that this will cause too many unnecessary read and write to the Firestore, especially, for a group chat application. I have currently implemented using a topic with uid. When a user logs in, subscribes to `uid` topic. Then when the user enters a chat room, add the user's uid into the firestore chat room subscription document. When a message published, read the document then send push messages to the uid topics in the document. This still requires firestore to keep track of subscriptions, but slightly less read and write

Comment: I'm still looking for a better solution, likely which doesn't involve the firestore.

Comment: @e-j5 I also have requirement on similar lines, Do you come up with any new simpler  approach ?
Slightly different requirement  please help me if you have any suggestion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67959489/firebase-user-login-from-multiple-devices-and-fcm-notification-using-topic-sub