# firebase : user login from multiple devices and fcm notification using topic subscription

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is my requirement in project :

My app is for a media posts, post can be edited. On edit post, i want to send notification to all those users who subscribed to the post notification.

**subscription code** :

On click of subscribe button flutter app will execute below code.

```
await firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(uniqueIdOfPost);
```

along with subscribe, app will also store information in firestore so that user can unsubscribe if required.

**Code to send notification :**

Here is my admin sdk backend script in nodejs (for now its backend script later i will convert it into cloud function)

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("/DriveA/firebase/adminsdk/firebase-adminsdk.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

var payload = {
  notification: {
    title: "Notification from Topic",
    body: "This is the body of the notification message."
  }
};

// This is unique ID of post.
var topic = "xpxpwd9856lsktppw";

admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
  });
```

suppose a case where user logged in into the app and subscribed to notification. On post edit my backend code runs and it sends notification to device.

So far so good as i am using single device for testing.

If the same user logs in from other device that device is not receiving notification. (may be because i subscribed to topic from other device).

Here is my question : how should i use topic subscription to handle this multi-device use case of a user ? does my use case can be solved using topic subscription or there is any other approach ?  it will be good if if someone points me the code which handle this use case.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot give you a working sample code, but what you can do is that you already stored list of subscribed topic somewhere in your firebase. you can subscribe all the topics when user sign in from a device, and unsubscribe when user sign out from a device.

Comment: @e-j5  Sure thanks for guidance.  Let me try your suggestion.  If it works, i will post code here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, It won't work when the user starts to subscribe new topic from one of the phones, the other phone won't get the notification.

What I do instead of the user(a device) subscribe to a topic, I subscribe the device to the `user id(uid)` topic.

Then, when a user subscribes to a topic, I add the `uid` to the `subscription` field of the posting in firebase. Then when you need to send notification relate to a posting, read the `subscription` field and send notification to the uids in the field.

Here is what I did.

```
1. A user login 
  - subscribeToTopic(uid)
2. When user subscribe to a posting
  - add uid to subscribe field
3. When sending notification
  - read uids from subscribe field
  - for all uids, `sendToTopic(uid)`
4. A user logout
  - unsubscribeToTopic(uid)
```

Comment: Thanks you for your research and ans , i will definitely try it and will post you back.

Comment: OK. I'm using access tokens in requests, and when user signing out,  I unsubscribe device to Topic(uid), but what if the token expired! in this case no way to catch the event of sign out to be be able to unsubscribe!